# "unrecognized selector" error when I use isEqualToDate:[NSDate date] when getting date info with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

In my project I get a list of dates from an XML string using an NSXMLParser.  The object (called DatesXML) that the parser puts the information into has a

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDate *DATE;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *NAME;
```

among many other properties.

My parser is going to return an array (called dateItemsFromXML) of DatesXML objects.  After the parser finishes, I do

```
NSMutableDictionary *datesFromXMLDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (DatesXML *item in dateItemsFromXML)
{
    [datesFromXMLDictionary setValue:item.DATE forKey:item.NAME];
}
```

Later, I do

```
if ([[datesFromXMLDictionary objectForKey:@"OneOfMyNames"] isEqualToDate:[NSDate date]])
```

I'm getting an "unrecognized selector" error on this `if` statement.  I put in a breakpoint, and when I put `po [datesFromXMLDictionary objectForKey:@"OneOfMyNames"]` in the Console, I get `(id) ... 12/3/2012`.

Why is the Console telling me it is an id object instead of an NSDate object?  Is that information lost when it is put into the dictionary (or anywhere else for that matter)?

Comment: Post the **exact** error message. And check the class of `item.DATE`. I guess it's NSString and not NSDate.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: I don't think so - item is a `DatesXML` object and the NAME property is declared in my .h as an NSDate, so that should make sure it's an NSDate object, right?  Otherwise it would be throwing a compile error saying I'm sending a string to a date in the `for` loop where I build the dictionary, right?

Comment: It is declared as NSDate, but you can assign any object to that variable, and I guess you assigned a NSString. If you get the NSString from an NSArray, a NSDictionary or any other method that returns `id` you won't get a compiler warning.

Comment: And this is a little bit of an abbreviation of my actual code, and I thought the Console giving me this as an (id) object meant I had narrowed it down to this, but I'll update with more if you think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The exact error message should be enough. It usually says to which object the selector was sent. Something like "[__NSCFString isEqualToDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". Then you know that your object is of type __NSCFString which is a NSString.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: oh you're right, it is telling me __NSCFString... and that does match a string that I would get from a stringFromDate: for a NSDateFormatter that I'm using... I'll look into this closer.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: Ah that was the key.  In my parser I was just taking the date as a string from the xml and putting it directly into the DATE property.  I put an NSDateFormatter in my parser to turn it into a date when I first read it in, and I'm not getting an error any longer.  Thanks for all your help - do you want to put that into an answer I can upvote and accept? Or I'll summarize it and answer myself, but I want to give you the credit if you want it.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch you should post this as an answer then the original poster could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Matthias Bauch in the comments, the root of my problem ended up being because I had an NSString in my .DATE property.  When the parser was loading up my DatesXML object, it loads everything in as a string by default.  As a result, it loaded my .DATE property with a string (and did so silently), even though .DATE is supposed to be an NSDate.

I put an NSDateFormatter into my parser to turn the string from the xml into an NSDate, then put that NSDate into my .DATE property.  That eliminated the error I was getting and I'm getting all the behavior I expected when I try to use the .DATE property elsewhere in my code.